# Declaring structure to avoid mixed declarations and code

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I'm compiling with `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` and I get the following warning:

`ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code`

This is because I need to perform certain operations before filling the array.

I wonder what would be a good way or alternative to initialize and declare `cars` so this warning can be avoided.

The code in question looks something like this:

```
int my_func() {
    typedef struct Car_ {
        char *brand;
        int amount;
        int color;
    } Car;

    int fixed = 0;
    int total1 = getAmountBase(brand1);
    int total2 = getAmountSub(brand2);
    int total3 = getAmountBase(brand3);
    int total4 = getAmountSub(brand4);
    int grand = getAmountBase(brand7);
    // more operations...
    if (grand7 != NULL) {
        grand7 = calcBase(grand7, total6);
        fixed = addGrand(grand7);
    }

    Car cars[] = {               // warning here.
        {"brand1", total1,  RED},
        {"brand2", total2,  RED},
        {"brand3", total3,  RED},
        {"brand4", total4,  RED},
        {"brand7", fixed,  RED},
    };

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it up front and assign the computed parts later:

```
Car cars[] = {
    {"brand1", -1,  RED},
    {"brand2", -1,  RED},
    {"brand3", -1,  RED},
    {"brand4", -1,  RED},
    {"brand7", -1,  RED},
};

...

cars[0].amount = total1;
cars[1].amount = total2;
/* etc */
```

Or, if suitable, compile with `-std=c99`.